# Merge two or more hash slices, i.e. only selected keys from the hashes

Tags: perl, merge, hashmap, perl-data-structures

I am writing a piece of code that receives arguments `%args` and has a configuration `%conf`. I need to pass *certain values* from *both of these hashes* to another Perl module while others are relevant only for my own code.

**How to merge two (or more) hashes slices** or **merge hashes while keeping only selected keys** in an elegant way?

Important points:

- The list of desired keys might be used as list or saved in an array.
- Values from `%args` shall override those from `%conf`.
- Keys not contained in `%args` nor `%conf` shall not be contained in `%result`.

Example input:

```
my %conf = (
     path  => '/usr/local/bin/',
     size  => 42,
     other => 'value', # isn't used
);
my %args = (
     path => '~/bin/', # overrides $conf{path}
     foo  => 'bar',
);
my @keys = qw<path size foo bar>;  # 'bar' isn't contained in either hash!
```

Expected result:

```
my %result = (
    path => '~/bin/', # from $args{patħ}
    size => 42,
    foo  => 'bar',
);
```

For a simple merge this is enough:

```
my %result = ( %conf, %args );
```

A simple hash slice is also simple:

```
my %slice = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } qw<foo bar baz>;
```

Reducing to the existing keys already needs a temporary variable:

```
my %keys = map { $_ => 1 } qw<foo bar baz>;
grep { $keys{$_} } %hash;
```

But putting it alltogether becomes quite complex:

```
my @keys = qw<foo bar baz>;
my %keys = map { $_ => 1 } @keys;
my %result = (
    map( { $_ => $conf{$_} } grep { $keys{$_} } keys %conf ),
    map( { $_ => $args{$_} } grep { $keys{$_} } keys %args ),
);
```

Is there some nicer way to code this?

Comment: This isn't really important, but `my %slice = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } qw<foo bar baz>;` is not a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices). You mean `@hash{ qw<foo bar baz> }`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You're correct--that is not exactly what is called a *hash slice*. I just didn't knew what the correct name is. What do you call that part of a hash that only contains a subset of keys?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

This is a response to your revised question. My best effort to write something clean just deletes any elements of the combined hash that aren't in `@keys`, using an intermediate `%wanted` hash to describe which hash keys appear in the array

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';


# Set up test data

my %conf = (
     path  => '/usr/local/bin/',
     size  => 42,
     other => 'value', # isn't used
);

my %args = (
     path => '~/bin/', # overrides $conf{path}
     foo  => 'bar',
);

my @keys = qw/ path size foo bar /;  # 'bar' isn't contained in either hash!


# Combine and select

my %wanted = map { $_ => 1 } @keys;

my %result = (%conf, %args);
delete @result{ grep { not $wanted{$_} } keys %result };


# Display the result

use Data::Dump;
dd \%result;
```

#### output

```
{ foo => "bar", path => "~/bin/", size => 42 }
```

---

### Original

This seems to fit the bill. I've copied the test data from your post

- The two hashes are combined into `%join`, with `%args` overriding `%conf` by putting it second in the list assignment
- Then the array `%result` is built by using slices to pull the required elements from `%join`
- I've used [Data::Dump](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) only to show the results of the preceding code
- Note that if there is a string in `@keys` that doesn't appear in *either* hash, then it will be included in `%results` with a value of `undef`
- *“The list of desired keys might be used as list or saved in an array.”*

  That's a very vague requirement. For this solution to work you need an array of keys, so simply store your list as an array

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';


# Set up test data

my %conf = (
     path  => '/usr/local/bin/',
     size  => 42,
     other => 'value', # isn't used
);

my %args = (
     path => '~/bin/', # overrides $conf{path}
     foo  => 'bar',
);

my @keys = qw/ path size foo /;


# Combine and select

my %join = (%conf, %args);

my %result;
@result{@keys} = @join{@keys};


# Display the result

use Data::Dump;
dd \%result;
```

#### output

```
{ foo => "bar", path => "~/bin/", size => 42 }
```

Comment: `my %result; @result{@keys} = @join{@keys};` can be written `my  %result = %join{@keys};` in 5.20+.

Comment: @Borodin: your code inserts `undef` values into `@result` for keys that are not contained in any input hash. I've updated the question for `@keys` to contain such a key.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer: That's what I said in my fourth bullet point. If that's *really* a problem then you have highly sensitive code — all that should be necessary is to use `defined` instead of `exists` — but the obvious way to exclude elements like that is to use a loop instead of a pair of slices. What do you need?

Comment: I was obviously skimming your answer too fast. I expect the other module to throw errors or misbehave if I pass keys with undisired `undef` values. I definitely need to exclude these keys.